# Embed Adobe Air app in iOS objective C app

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

We have a project developed in Flex, which we have already successfully been able to integrate with our Android app. The best part is that Android lets you embed adobe air app as part of another Android app so you can integrated seamlessly. We would like to do similar thing with iOS app but cant any way to sort of embed Air app in iOS Objective-C based app. We can launch one app from another but thats not what we want. We would like to show show flex app in half part of the screen of iOS obj C app. If anyone has managed to do such thing, are there any other tricks to achieve such thing? ( Flex app needs to load data do its own bits)

Comment: any progress here? I'd be interested in solutions as well

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to have both apps on screen at the same time? 
 Either way the best approach to this is probably to have your objective-c app be a native extension to your flex app, as opposed to the other way around.  I dont know of any way to include the flex app as part of an objective-c app.  If you make your native app an extension, when you start it the native view will be ontop of your flex view, so if you only make it take half the screen, your flex app will be visible below it on the other half of the screen.
This isnt elegant or something I would recommend, but it is the only way I know of to accomplish what I believe you are trying to do.